# Excel Chart, Reverse X Axis direction with values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I currently have my chart set up like so :

[image]

How can I change the order so that it is read from left to right?

Right now it goes from recent date to last date. When I Reverse Categories, it also shifts the Y Axis to the right hand side, I want to keep the Y axis on the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You right click on the axis itself, and select format axis, or you can simply double click the axis depending on your version.

Then look for the setting `categories in reverse order`, click this box.

See image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks peter, This is what I want, however It also shifts the Y axis to the right, I want to keep the Y axis on the Left side.

Comment: I don't think there is an option to reverse the order AND keep the Y-axis on the left, apart from re-arranging your actual data set from which you plot the series

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to keep the Y axis on the left side, for anyone who stumbles across this on Google. Click the X axis, then format axis, and under Vertical axis crosses, select At maximum category.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the Y axis in the same place go to Format Axis>Axis Options>Labels and change label position to "Next to Axis"